# How to link two remote git repositories to one local repository and flexibly sync from both?

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I have been working with Git (Bitbucket), and I know how to link multiple remote repositories to one local repository, as I have seen in many tutorials available online, like this https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories and this https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/2464/how-to-use-git-with-multiple-remote-repositories/

What I am trying to achieve is little different. I have two remote repositories, say `repo1` and `repo2`. Both repositories contain 3 branches - `master` branch, `release/1.0` branch, and `release/2.0` branch. My project is a generic Java application. `repo1` contains only java files, while `repo2` contains only JAR files, which are binary files.

I don't have any dependency management system like maven. I am trying to achieve this - When I switch to `release/1.0` branch, my java files will change according to `repo1` and the JAR files should also change according to `repo2`. Similarly, when I switch to `release/2.0` branch, my java files should change according to `repo1` and the JAR files should also change according to `repo2`. JAR files are different in release branches.

I will not be pushing JAR files to `repo2`, I don't have such a use case. I will be pushing only Java files, that too, to `repo1`.

Is this possible? or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using scripts. On [this repository](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts) there is a bunch of examples for copying:

The script you could do, could be named like **checkout-branch**,and the argument *$1* would be the branch you need to checkout.

```
#!/bin/sh
# checkout branch from different remote repositories

git checkout repo1 $1 && git checkout repo2 $1
```

Then you can use it on your console like:

```
./checkout-branch.sh release/2.0
```

Remember to change the permissions on the file to be able to execute it,
make the script executable with command

`chmod +x <fileName>`

PD: for pushing, deleting etc, you could do the same.

Comment: thanks @Damian229 Let me go through this and will up-vote / accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your files properly seperated, you could use a git submodule.

Basically you add repo2 as a dependency to repo1, within git. This way you have all your files locally, but seperated into two repos. When you make a new branch for repo1 though, you'll also have to make a new branch for repo2 and link it in the new repo1 branch.

Usually this works like a dependency normally would: Your submodule is a specific commit of repo2. When you want to update, you update to a new commit. So you'd have to work around this to achieve your specific use case.

**Edit:**

For starters, you can add a submodule to your repo using `git submodule add http://repo2.git`, which would make a new folder `repo2`, which will be the root of your repo2. In there you can work as if in the other repo. Your repo will only have the config for that added.

When you want to update, you go to the `repo1` root and update the submodule with `git submodule update --remote`.

Comment: I was thinking about submodules, but dont know how to achieve the whole thing

Comment: I updated my answer with how to install a submodule.